# Cauchy property and limit in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers with the property that
\begin{equation}
  \forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall\color{red}m
\color{red}>\color{red}n\geq N:\quad\lvert x_{n}-x_{m}\lvert<\varepsilon.
\end{equation}
Given the above, I would like to understand what the expression
\begin{equation}
  \lim_{\substack{m,n\to\infty\\ m>n}}\lvert x_{n}-x_{m}\rvert=0
\end{equation}
exactly means and why this ''Cauchy property'' suffices for $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to admit a limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double sequence $a_{m,n}$ is formally a function $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$. We say $\lim\limits_{m,n\to\infty} a_{m,n}=a$ if:

$\forall\epsilon>0 \ \ \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N} \ \ \forall m,n\geq n_0: |a_{m,n}-a|<\epsilon$.

So this is a natural generalization of a regular limit. The condition that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy exactly means that $\lim\limits_{m,n\to\infty} |x_m-x_n|=0$, this is immediate from the definition.

Comment: Ok, I understand the part concerning the double sequence. What I do not yet understand is why I can treat the above condition as a "Cauchy property" even though it only holds whenever $m>n$? Doesn't Cauchy ask for a bit more than that?

Comment: Well, if it holds for $m > n$, then it holds for $m < n$ by symmetry thanks to the $|.|$, and it trivially holds if $m=n$.

Comment: @User129599 Exactly what Bruno B wrote. In many books it is not written as $|x_m-x_n|<\epsilon$ for all $m>n\geq n_0$, but just for all $m,n\geq n_0$, which is equivalent. After all, if we have any two indices $m,n$ then one of them will be larger than the other. (except for the case $m=n$, but then $|x_m-x_n|=0<\epsilon$ trivially)

Comment: @Mark I see your point, thanks! I think the trouble I am having comes from the fact that, in the problem I am looking at, one (temporarily) works only with the sequence $(x_{n})$ defined on $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ such that the condition $\lvert x_{n}-x_{m}\rvert<\varepsilon$ only makes sense for $n<m$.

Comment: @User129599 Perhaps you should ask about that specific problem then. The two definitions are totally equivalent, but in some cases one of them is more helpful than the other. (for example when we talk about Cauchy criterion for series it makes sense to assume $m>n$, because it's much easier to write the sum then) So in order to help from this point, we need to know what the problem is.